# Can a HDD write to two separate partitions at the same time safely?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, partitioning

I have a Mac Pro 2009 with multiple internal storage disks, one of them being a 4TB HDD with 3 partitions. 2 of these are used as Time Machine backup destinations, one for my Mac Pro and one for my MacBook Pro.

My question is, can I safely run Time Machine on both devices at the same time, or do the separate partitions create problems for the physical writing process?

Comment: A traditional spinning drive cannot write to two places at the same time, it would write one block, then move to write the next... If your question is can your PC manage writing to two distinct partitions "at the same time", the answer is certainly, but realize there may be some delay on occasion depending on what you are doing. In other words, the write operations will queue and be written in a FIFO order. The hard drive doesn't care if it's one or two partitions, its just ones and zeros being written to different spots on the drive.

Comment: @acejavelin thank you! Its not necessarily speed I'm concerned about so much as damaging the physical disk itself. Your explanation clarified exactly what I was worried about.

Comment: Then I agree with Keltari's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely safe. However, writing two backups at the same time will take longer than writing two backups one at a time. The two backups will be in contention for reading and writing the data to one physical disk.